# Individual elements of an array as a function parameters in C?

Tags: arrays, c, parameters

Suppose I have a function `foo`:

```c
int foo(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Can I in any way call `foo` with an array and have each elements of the array act as one parameter?

e.g:

```c
int arr[2] = {1, 2};
foo(arr); // Should return 3
```

In JavaScript I can do:

```js
let arr = [1, 2];
foo(...arr); // Returns 3
```

Is there anything similar in C?

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible. You will have to call the function `foo` like this:

```
int arr[2] = { 1, 2 };
foo( arr[0], arr[1] );
```

However, it is possible to redefine the function `foo` like this:

```
int foo( int arr[2] )
{
    return arr[0] + arr[1];
}
```

Now, you can call the function `foo` like this:

```
int arr[2] = { 1, 2 };
foo( arr );
```

Comment: Actually it should be `int foo( int arr[static 2] )`

Comment: @tstanisl: Using the keyword `static` has the advantage that it may allow additional compiler optimizations. However, it is not necessary. I am not using it, because I'm afraid that it would make the code harder to understand for OP. Also, it would make the code incompatible with C++.

Comment: The value `2` in `int arr[2]` is de-facto ignored. Some compilers generate warnings if the size of passed array is inconsistent with the function declaration but this warning is not justified by the  C standard. IMO, using `static` makes the declaration visually distinct from a definition of an array saving "WTF moment" when using `sizeof arr`. I think that only `int *arr`/`int arr[]`/`int (*arr)[2]`/`int arr[static 2]` are valid, the last one is the most flexible and self-documenting. Actually, the parameter `int arr[2]` is the most confusing one.

Comment: The compatibility with C++ is the lesser concern, because C and C++ are distinct languages sharing only some syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an array to a function, but in doing so it decays to a pointer so you don't know what the size is.  You would need to pass the size as a separate parameter, then your function can loop through the elements.

```
int foo(int *arr, int len)
{
    int i, sum;
    for(i=0, sum=0; i<len; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
int arr[2] = {1, 2};
foo(arr, 2);
```

Or, assuming the array was declared locally:

```
foo(arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Only by writing out the references longhand:

```
foo(arr[0], arr[1]);
```